# Application of Sylow Theorems

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I am trying to prove:

> If $G$ is a group of order $2^5\cdot7^2\cdot 17$ then there is a unique group of order $2^5\cdot 17$

I can prove the existence using Sylow theorems, but the uniqueness is not easy to me!

Can someone give me a hint how to do this? A hint, don't give me the entire answer cause I need o learn it for my qualyfing exam!

Thank you everyone!

Comment: I've not done any calculation yet, but does $G$ have normal Sylow $p$-subgroup for somprime $p$?. If it is the case, take the quotient group of $G$ by this normal subgroup, and apply Sylow thm. on the quotient group.

Comment: Getting uniqueness will likely require some ingenuity with using sylow theorems 2 and 3, I would suggest using the congruence and normalizer parts of the 3rd theorem to show that the number of subgroups of size $2^5 \cdot 17$ can only be one (the alternative options would require too many unique elements due to the modularity condition; you may wanna start with p=7 and then argue what that implies for the subgroups of the size of interest).

Comment: @Justin Benfield you mean using actions? Could you be just a little more specific, algebra is my weakness haha

Comment: It's been a long time since I did much problem solving with the sylow theorems, but it's a common strategy to use the coprimality of the involved subgroups and sylow theorems 2 and 3 when trying to show that a subgroup of interest is the only one of it's size, especially when there are 3 distinct primes (or even easier when there are only 2). You can get a lot of value out of the implications about possible number of conjugate (and hence isomorphic) sylow-p subgroups of a given order, $p^n$, which can quickly eliminate otherwise plausible possibilities.

Comment: Does the direct product of a non-abelian group of order $14$ with a group of order $2^4\cdot 7\cdot 17$ have a unique subgroup of order $2^5\cdot 17$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once again this is not true. There are many counterexamples. As j.p. pointed out in comments, the direct product of a dihededral group of order $14$ and a cyclic group of order $2^4 \cdot 7 \cdot 17$ does not have a unique such subgroup: it has $7$ of them.

Comment: thanks a lot man, you were right all time! It isn't true. Damn!! Thank you so so much!! This exam will kill me